# What dimensions should I be using to create a mobile app header? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm a high school senior working on app development for an engineering senior project and I've run into a little block with the HTML/CSS. I created an initial prototype for the app using Adobe XD, and it looks a little like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4V3G.png

The initial dimensions for the header and footer elements in the prototype are 70px high, however, when I put this in my CSS and run a mobile emulator, it turns out looking more like this:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YcFe.png

I also tried converting to em/rem, but that didn't help. I know mobile screens have a higher pixel density than laptops/desktops but I don't know how much higher. Does anyone have any suggestions for getting the header and footer elements to be the proper height on the screen?

EDIT: Including HTML/CSS in question for reference

CSS:

```
body{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
padding:0;
  }
wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  clear:both;
}

#head{
  width:100%;
  height:4.313rem;
  font-size:40pt;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  text-align:center;
  color:#707070;
  }

#divider{
  width:100%;
  height:0.063rem;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}

#midcontainer{
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 8.75rem);
    background-color:#fafafa;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#midscroll{
     width:calc(100% + 20px);
     height:calc(100% - 8.75rem);
     overflow:auto;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
  }

#midbody{
  width:100%;
  min-height:calc(100% - 8.75rem);
  font-size:12pt;
  text-align:justify;
}

#foot{
  width:100%;
  height:4.375rem;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="Home">
  <div align="center" style="height:100vh;width:100vw;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:1px solid transparent;">
    <div id="head">
      <p style="position:relative;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);">Upcoming Tasks</p>
    </div> <!--end head-->
    <div id="divider">
    </div> <!--end divider-->

    <div id="midcontainer">
      <div id="midscroll">
        <div id="midbody">
          <p style="padding-left:0.313rem;padding-right:0.313rem;">
            *Body elements here*
          </p>
        </div> <!--end midbody-->
      </div> <!--end midscroll-->
    </div> <!--end midcontiner END OF MIDDLE CONTENT-->

    <div id="foot">
      <img id="Home" style="height:4.375rem;width:4.375rem;padding-right:1.125rem;" src="https://imgur.com/C5zD29C.png">
      <img id="Create" style="height:4.375rem;width:4.375rem;padding-right:1.188rem;" src="https://imgur.com/5UhZ0e9.png">
      <img id ="Calendar" style="height:4.375rem;width:4.375rem;padding-right:1.125rem;" src="https://imgur.com/nUTj5zs.png">
      <img id="Achievements" style="height:4.375rem;width:4.375rem;" src="https://imgur.com/4WrWF7T.png">
    </div> <!--end foot-->
  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: Could you please share your code!

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify which attempt?

Comment: attempt in the sense `code`

Comment: edited main post to include it, sorry! I'm working on multiple computers so I didn't have access to it when I made the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this into the `<head>` of your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```